# Can I power Raspberry Pi Zero with regular phone charger (Samsung, Apple, etc)?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi documentation says that Pi Zero (and Zero - W) requires 1.2A PSU Current capacity and 150mA Typical bare-board active current consumption.
I have seen several posts about Pi 3 with phone charger but not the Zero with phone charger (I guess it's because it came out recently?).
I also have read somewhere that Pi will only draw as much as it needs?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware question.

Comment: In general, questions like this are probably better suited on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh didnt know one exist... thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All RPi models are the same in this regard. So long as the charger meets or exceeds the minimum requirements, it will work fine.